# if self.bitmask |= flag adds an option, how to remove one?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, c, ipad

Example

```
self.accessibilityTraits |= UIAccessibilityTraitAdjustable;
```

adds the UIAccessibilityTraitAdjustable option. But how to remove an option from the mask like this, without having to set everything?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

*And* it with the complement of the flag:

```
self.accessibilityTraits &= ~UIAccessibilityTraitAdjustable;
```

If `self.accessibilityTraits` was:

```
  000110
```

and `UIAccessibilityTraitAdjustable` is:

```
  000100
```

(*these values are examples; I haven't looked-up the real values*)

then  `self.accessibilityTraits &= ~UIAccessibilityTraitAdjustable;` is:

```
  000110
& 111011
= 000010
```

Comment: "Compliment": good answer. "Complement": the bitwise inverse.

Answer (score 7):

Try `self.accessibilityTraits &= ~UIAccessibilityTraitAdjustable;`

`~` inverts the bits therefor the bits to be retained are 1 now and the bits to be cleared are 0. ANDing it with the left hand side variable will retain the bits which has 1s in the corresponding locations of `~UIAccessibilityTraitAdjustable` and will clear the bits which has 0s in the corresponding locations of `~UIAccessibilityTraitAdjustable`.

Answer (score 6):

`self.accessibilityTraits &= ~UIAccessibilityTraitAdjustable;`

`~UIAccessibilityTraitAdjustable` inverts all bits, leaving the one(s) representing your option to `0`. The binary *and* takes care of the rest.

Answer (score 5):

```
self.accessibilityTraits &= ~UIAccessibilityTraitAdjustable;
```

The `~` inverts the bitmask (NOT) to contain all bits *except* the one given, and the `&=` `AND`s the result with the variable to remove the bit.

Comment: OK so this will remove only UIAccessibilityTraitAdjustable without adding all other flags? I just want to remove UIAccessibilityTraitAdjustable but don't want to add "every other except this one".

Comment: @openfrog Yes, this will just clear/remove the single flag you give, leaving all others unaffected.